# Create array using foreach while grouping every 2 items into key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

i got a string which i want to explode into an array but
the issuse is that i need every couple of item to be group.

**Example string:**

```
http://www.example.com, example, http://www.example2.com, example2, http://www.example3.com, example3, http://www.example.com4, example4, http://www.example5.com, example5, http://www.example6.com, example6,
```

**what i would like to achieve is:**

```
array(  
   [1]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example.com',  
        [name] => 'example',  
   ),  
   [2]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example2.com',  
        [name] => 'example2',  
   ),  
   [3]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example3.com',  
        [name] => 'example3',  
   ),  
   [4]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example4.com',  
        [name] => 'example4',  
   ),  
   [5]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example5.com',  
        [name] => 'example5',  
   ),  
   [6]=>array(  
        [url] => 'http://www.example5.com',  
        [name] => 'example6',  
   ),  
);
```

and so on...
i tried to create such an array in many ways but i guess i lack
the know how and would really apreaciate your help.  ;)

EDIT 1 (tried so far):

```
$csv_arr    =   array();
$keycounter =   1;
$counter    =   1;


foreach($csv_data as $dataitem) {

    if($counter % 2 == 0) {
        $csv_arr[$keycounter]['keyword']    =   $dataitem;
        $keycounter++;
    }
    else {
        $csv_arr[$keycounter]['url']        =   $dataitem;      
    }

    $counter++;

}
```

Comment: So WHAT did you try so far? Show code!

Comment: My code doesent work - i dont need a little fix, i need an idea, a guideline... nevetheless - i added my un-working code (what for!?!) while i try @kingkero code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can explode on `,` (so you are sure there are no `,` in the URLs or strings following them) you can use a code like this

```
$exploded = explode(',', $string);
$max = count($exploded);
$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i+=2) {
    $result[] = array(
        'url' => $exploded[$i],
        'name' => $exploded[($i+1)]
    );
}
```

Comment: This is great - it actully does what my code does so i guess i have a problem in string but your way is much much more elegant - love it and learned something new ;) thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help (a little). Make sure your string contains `,` only as delimeter (as I mentioned) and maybe remove the trailing `,` (`(r)trim` is your friend)

Comment: yee, my string has no comma at the end of a line (textarea)... thats why i tought my code was wrong - in any case i learned something new which is always cool. thanks mate.